# How to set entry path when using curlftpfs?

Tags: linux, curlftpfs

The default path seems to be `/www/www` which locks me out of other subdomains I have on the server.

I looked through `man curlftpfs` and `curlftpfs -h` for any way to specify entry path to no avail.

I also created a new ftp subaccount on my remote server and explicitly set the directory parameter to `/` but curlftpfs still mounts only `/www/www`

It should be noted I can access anything on my remote server through Filezilla, which I assume means I have no permission-related issue.

**Update**: I created yet another ftp sub account on my remote server, explicitly setting the directory to `www/subdomain` and `curlftpfs` seems to have picked it up as `pwd`

I don't find this a satisfying answer because:

1. `curlftpfs` doesn't seem consistent in regards to whether it picks up a path as `pwd`
2. `/` is accessible through Filezilla, so I expect it to be accessible via `curlftpfs` as well.